# Is there any good tree manipulation (template) libraries for C++ out there?

Tags: c++, tree

Is there any good tree manipulation (template) libraries for C++ out there that can do basic things like binary tree.

Though it is not difficult to write a binary tree all from scratch, but I'm really surprised that it is not so easy to find one ready-for-use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need the tree for? There may already be something in the STL or Boost that satisfies your need. For example: the STL `std::map<key,value>` is usually implemented as a balanced binary tree.

There is also [tree.hh](http://tree.phi-sci.com/) which implements an STL-like n-way tree.

Comment: Just because the STL map is implemented using a tree doesn't mean it provides a tree-like data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Trees are subsets of [graphs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_theory_review.html). There are plenty of graph libraries out there, such as [Boost Graph Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html). You will have to add your vertices as you want and then use any one of the many [visitors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/graph/doc/visitor_concepts.html) to traverse your tree.

Alternatively, you could custom make one with standard containers (think of a root node as containing 2 children that have a value and may have 2 other children).

Comment: is there an example on how to utilize BGL to implement, for example, a binary tree. I'm having trouble using it because of its abstractness.

Comment: I can't think of specific binary tree examples, but a binary tree is a directed graph. Here's an example of a directed graph search using DFS (depth first search): http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/graph/example/dfs-example.cpp

Answer (score 1):

ACE has an implementation of Red Black tree.  It is fairly easy to use.

[link text](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.7.4/html/ace/a00512.html)